# Aver monitor gone dark in one corner?

Tags: display

I was just on my PC watching a Livestream and suddenly the bottom right corner has gone darker than the rest of the screen almost like a shadow? I haven't done anything to the monitor.

Comment: It is like that all the time or just while livestreaming?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like part of the backlight died - *typically* Its top and bottom arrays, but in your case sounds like one LED of an array died.

Since the backlight is built into the LCD panel, there's not much you can do yourself.

Comment: Odd. I just changed input into my PS4 and now it's gone off my PS4 & PC?